# Exception when access inner class reflectively

Tags: java, reflection

Here is a sample program tested in Java 1.5.

I wonder why the two approaches below have different result. Is it a bug or a kind of Java feature?

```
package test;

public class TestOut {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // works
        new TestIn();

        // throws IllegalAccessException
        Class.forName("test.TestOut$TestIn").newInstance();
    }

    private static class TestIn {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The class is private, hence the `IllegalAccessException` - you can use:

```
Class cls = Class.forName(...);
Constructor c = cls.getDeclaredConstructors()[0];
c.setAccessible(true);
c.newInstance();
```

For the record, the exception has a message, which is quite descriptive. Next time don't omit such information from the question. (actually, I'm not sure this message exists on Java 1.5, does it?)

> Class test.Test can not access a member of class test.TestOut$TestIn with modifiers "private"

The problem lies in the `verifyMemberAccess(..)` method of `sun.reflect.Reflection`, and that it doesn't take into account enclosing classes. If a member (constructor) is private, access is denied.

Comment: How come explicit `new` works even if it's `private`, though?

Comment: I think because reflection eliminates the context, and the context is that the inner class belongs to the outer. The Class object itself retains the reference to the enclosing class, but the Constructor doesn't.

Comment: 3x,Bozho. the "context" is what I am really wondering. IMHO, the Constructor should have enough information to know the enclsong class, and there seems no good reason to implement it in this way.

Comment: @MikeJiang, @polygenelubricants - see my update. The problem is actually elsewhere ;)

Comment: I was about to file a bug, but there is a bug in the password reset option of sun.com. I reported it, so first they'd have to resolve it, and then I'll be able to file the real bug ;)

Answer (score 3):

This is [Bug ID 4221909](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4221909):

> **Synopsys**: (reflect) `Class.newInstance()` throws `IllegalAccess`<strike>`Error`</strike>`Exception` when the class has an inner non-`public class`
> **State**: 6-Fix Understood,   bug
> **Priority**: 4-Low
> **Submit Date**: 19-MAR-1999