# IllegalAccessException on using reflection

Tags: java, reflection

I was trying to learn reflection and I came across this IllegalAccessException. Please see the following code:

```
public class ReflectionTest
{
      public static void main(String[] args)
      {
           Set<String> myStr = new HashSet<String>();
           myStr.add("obj1");
           Iterator itr = myStr.iterator();
           Method mtd = itr.getClass().getMethod("hasNext");
           System.out.println(m.invoke(it));
      }
}
```

When I tried to run this program, I got the following:

```
Exception in thread "main" IllegalAccessException
```

I don't understand what's going on. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Should `System.out.println(m.invoke(it));` be `System.out.println(mtd.invoke(itr));`? Looks like you're trying to access a private member.

Answer (score 8):

The troublesome piece of code is this:

```
itr.getClass().getMethod
```

You probably wanted `hasNext` on the `Iterator` class. What you have written is the `HashMap.KeyIterator` class, which according the Java language access specifiers (or at least the rough interpretation of JDK 1.0 used by reflection) is not available to your code.

Use instead:

```
Iterator.class.getMethod
```

(And if it wasn't for learning purposes, stay away from reflection.)

Comment: Why discourage the use of reflection? It can be a very powerful and helpful tool: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/101187/are-there-problems-with-using-reflection

Comment: Please don't discourage a useful tool with no elaboration nor justification.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot access it, because the Iterator is a private inner class. More explanation can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2910168/exception-when-access-inner-class-reflectively).

Answer (score 0):

It's apparent that your currently executing method does not have access to the method named *`hasNext`*, e.g., by it being `private` or `protected`. You could try to enable access to it using `method.setAccessible(true);`

It might also be that you have some [restrictions defined](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/security/tour2/step2.html) in your `security manager` (which, if you use e.g., `linux`, *might* have been included default from the distributions java package).

**[EDIT]** As it turns out, Tom Hawtin identified the correct root cause. You are indeed operating on `HashMap.KeyIterator`. Although the solution would be to use `Iterator.class` instead of `itr.getClass()` you could still enable access to it using `setAccessible(true)`.

Comment: `hasNext` isn't private. Your second statement may be true.

Comment: @adarshr, as it turns out `hasNext` *[has private](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Java-Document/6.0-JDK-Core/Collections-Jar-Zip-Logging-regex/java/util/HashMap.java.htm)* access on the iterator of type `HashMap.KeyIterator` which your code operatons on.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you should use getDeclaredMethod (among other issues). I don't bother to remember Reflection API details (they're for the compiler!), but in your case compare your code with that produced by [dp4j](http://dp4j.com):

```
$ javac -Averbose=true -All -cp dp4j-1.2-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar ReflectionTest.java 
ReflectionTest.java:6: Note: 
import java.util.*;

public class ReflectionTest {

public ReflectionTest() {
    super();
}

@com.dp4j.Reflect()
public static void main(String[] args) throws java.lang.ClassNotFoundException, java.lang.NoSuchFieldException, java.lang.IllegalAccessException, java.lang.NoSuchMethodException, java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException, java.lang.InstantiationException, java.lang.IllegalArgumentException {
    final java.lang.reflect.Constructor hashSetConstructor = Class.forName("java.util.HashSet").getDeclaredConstructor();
    hashSetConstructor.setAccessible(true);
    Set<String> myStr = (.java.util.Set<.java.lang.String>)hashSetConstructor.newInstance();
    final java.lang.reflect.Method addWithEMethod = Class.forName("java.util.Set").getDeclaredMethod("add", .java.lang.Object.class);
    addWithEMethod.setAccessible(true);
    addWithEMethod.invoke(myStr, new .java.lang.Object[1][]{"obj1"});
    final java.lang.reflect.Method iteratorMethod = Class.forName("java.util.Set").getDeclaredMethod("iterator");
    iteratorMethod.setAccessible(true);
    Iterator itr = (.java.util.Iterator)iteratorMethod.invoke(myStr);
    final java.lang.reflect.Method hasNextMethod = Class.forName("java.util.Iterator").getDeclaredMethod("hasNext");
    hasNextMethod.setAccessible(true);
    final java.lang.reflect.Method printlnWithbooleanMethod = Class.forName("java.io.PrintStream").getDeclaredMethod("println", .java.lang.Boolean.TYPE);
    printlnWithbooleanMethod.setAccessible(true);
    printlnWithbooleanMethod.invoke(System.out, new .java.lang.Object[1][]{hasNextMethod.invoke(itr)});
}
```

}

```
    public static void main(String[] args)
                       ^
...

$ java ReflectionTest
true
```

The only change you need to do is annotate your main method with @com.dp4j.Reflect:

```
$ vim ReflectionTest.java
import java.util.*;

public class ReflectionTest
{
        @com.dp4j.Reflect
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
                Set<String> myStr = new HashSet<String>();
                myStr.add("obj1");
                Iterator itr = myStr.iterator();
                // Method mtd = itr.getClass().getMethod("hasNext");
                System.out.println(itr.hasNext());
        }
}
```

NB: this works only with dp4j-1.2-SNAPSHOT (I've just added suport for it). If you don't use Maven, download the jar from [here](https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/dp4j/dp4j/1.2-SNAPSHOT/). You find the test case with your problem [here](http://code.google.com/p/dp4j/source/browse/src/test/java/ReflectionTest.java).