# method access denied while calling java subclass protected method

Tags: java, reflection, methods, illegalaccessexception

I have the following issue: I have a class, trying to use reflection to call one of its OWN protected methods, and I'm getting an exception:
java.lang.IllegalAccessException: access to method denied

Can someone maybe shed some light on this?

The base class:

```
public abstract class BaseReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // invoke the correct event method:
        Method method;
        try {
            method = this.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("testMethod");
            method.invoke(this);
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
             // ... display exception message
        }
    }

    protected void testMethod() {
    }

}
```

The derived concrete class:

```
class MyReceiver extends BaseReceiver {
    @Override
    protected void testMethod() {
        // display error message
    }
}
```

Comment: Does it work with `BaseReceiver.class.getDeclaredMethod` ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5184284/illegalaccessexception-on-using-reflection

Comment: @KazekageGaara: that other question is about methods not otherwise accessible. Here, he tries to call his own method.

Comment: Oh sorry about it then. I just thought it might be useful.

Answer (score 17):

Protected methods are accessible just from the package, the the class itself or the classes that extends it.

As far as I can suppose (based on the `Exception`) your extended class (`MyReceiver`) is in another package then the super class (`BaseReceiver`). Meaning:

1. `MyReceiver` and `BaseReceiver` isn't in the same package;
2. `BaseReceiver` doesn't extends `MyReceiver`;

Now, as you can see on your code, you are doing: `method = this.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("testMethod");` this seems ok, but it isn't what you intend. As this method will return `MyReceiver.testMethod()` method, and this is not accessible from `BaseReceiver` (as you can see you are using `this.getClass()`, what returns the instance class, in this case `MyReceiver`).

You could do something:

```
...
method = BaseReceiver.class.getDeclaredMethod("testMethod");
...
```

with this you are instructing that you want the protected method being declared on `BaseReceiver` class. Of course when you invoke it later with `method.invoke(this);` you will invoke the overridden method.

*But it doesn't make sense to use reflection in such case, as you have `testMethod()` available, and invoking it (simple as this.testMethod()) you will invoke the overridden one.*

Another possibility is to `setAccessible(true)` on the method like:

```
method = getClass().getDeclaredMethod("testMethod");
method.setAccessible(true);
method.invoke(this);
```

Comment: +1 Just call `testMethod()` directly.  Reflection is a bad idea here.

Answer (score 1):

The static type of `this` in `BaseReceiver` is `BaseReceiver`, so you wouldn't normally have access to `MyReceiver.testMethod`. Apart from which, the reflection APIs check the caller class, not instance (which is nuts itself considering what reflection is for).

You should be able to use `BaseReceiver.testMethod`.

Reflection is a bad idea in most (but not all) cases it is used.