# Generate IllegalAccessException

Tags: java, illegalaccessexception

I am testing an algorithm for StringSearch and the algorithm has many IllegalAccessExceptions in it.

I wanted to test that the code is working fine with the exceptions...and it is important also to test them as they call some functions when the exception occurs.

I just wanted to know how can i implicitly generate the exception.

I am trying to use the Java Security Manager but don't know how to use it to revoke the program's access to String class.

Comment: I don't understand. What has a StringSearch algorithm to do with IllegalAccessExceptions?

Comment: Please write the code where you throws that exception

Comment: Why not just `throw new WhateverException()` in places that you like to test? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5184284/illegalaccessexception-on-using-reflection problem might be your solution

Answer (score 1):

try using Mockito to stub the method throws exception

```
 doThrow(new RuntimeException()).when(mockedList).clear();

 //following throws RuntimeException:
 mockedList.clear();
```

http://gojko.net/2009/10/23/mockito-in-six-easy-examples/

http://mockito.googlecode.com/svn/tags/1.7/javadoc/org/mockito/internal/stubbing/Stubber.html

Comment: Here is the code that throws the exception

try {
                    int o = offset.getInt(text);
                    char[] t = (char[]) value.get(text);
                    return instance.searchChars(t, textStart + o, textEnd + o,
                            getChars(pattern), processed)
                            - o;

                } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
                    synchronized (activeStringAccess) {
                        activeStringAccess = new StringAccess();
                    }

Comment: `private INSTANCE_CLASS instance;
doThrow(new IllegalAccessException()).when(instance).searchChars(any(), any(), any(), any(), any());`

Comment: Thanks for reply but
The program is saying that it is not able to resolve doThrow

Comment: You need add mockito lib to your classpath.

Comment: I did this
import org.mockito.*;

Stringsearchss4 = new BNDMWildcardsCI();

Mockito.doThrow(new IllegalAccessException()).when(ss4).searchChars(cc,pattern3);

it is saying argument to when is not a mock

Comment: Stringsearch ss4 = mock(BNDMWildcardsCI.class);

Comment: I am getting following exception   

Exception in thread "main" org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: 
Checked exception is invalid for this method!
Invalid: java.lang.IllegalAccessException

Comment: The issue that I have identified is SearcChars does not throw that exception it is the offset.getInt(text) that throws the IllegalAccessException
but I can't mock the method as the class for offset is final

Comment: I have tried to use SecurityManager like below SecurityManager SecMgr = new SecurityManager(); SecMgr.checkPackageAccess("java.lang.reflect.Field"); but dont know how to revoke permission to a method in the package or revoke access to package itself